# PyQt4: Connect custom signal with slot in new style

Tags: python, signals, pyqt4, slot

I wrote the following class, which has a custom signal called `signal_incremented`

```
class QThread_Sniffer(QtCore.QThread):

    signal_incremented = pyqtSignal(int, name="incremented")

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        #
        # do something
        #

        self.signal_incremented.emit(42)
```

Now I want to connect this signal to a slot in another class which is creating an instance of this QThread.

This works

```
class Dialog_Capturing(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.lcdNumber_packetCount = QLCDNumber()
        self.worker_sniffer = QThread_Sniffer()
        self.worker_sniffer.signal_incremented[int].connect(self.counterIncremented)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
        def counterIncremented(self, number):
            self.lcdNumber_packetCount.display(number)
```

but I would like to use the new style of connecting slots and signals, however I don't know how to use it in this case.

```
self.connect(
    self.worker_sniffer.signal_incremented,
    SIGNAL(), # < ===== What do I need to put here?
    self.counterIncremented
)
```

Comment: Did you check [the docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html?highlight=signals)? It seems to me that you were already using the new style.

Comment: You are indeed already using the new style. The old style was with `SIGNAL()`

Comment: Yes, I am. I was just not sure, what to put as second argument in `self.connect()`. Now I create the custom signal with a name parameter and provide this name in the `@pyqtSlot()` decorator. Now it works. I don't need the whole `self.connect()` call at all.